# How to mark a Scala var as partially overriding a parent

Tags: scala, overriding, getter-setter

Consider the following simple trait

```
trait Parent {
  def x: Int = 0
}
```

Now consider an implementing class that wishes to define `x` to be mutable.

```
class Child extends Parent {
  var x: Int = 1
}
```

This won't work, because

```
7 |  var x: Int = 1
  |      ^
  |      error overriding method x in trait Parent of type => Int;
  |        variable x of type Int needs `override` modifier
```

But the `override` modifier won't work either. If I write

```
override var x: Int = 1
```

I get

```
7 |  override var x: Int = 1
  |               ^
  |               setter x_= overrides nothing
```

This makes sense. `var` is implicitly defining two methods, one called `x` and one called `x_=`. The former requires the `override` modifier but the latter is not an override.

Obviously, I can implement this with a `private var` and explicit methods

```
class Child extends Parent {
  private var _x: Int = 1

  override def x: Int = _x
  def x_=(value: Int): Unit = {
    _x = value
  }
}
```

But this seems very high in getter/setter boilerplate for Scala's tastes. Is there a way to mark `var x` as partially overriding the parent's body?

Comment: I'm wondering if trying to make that approach work is a good idea. A `def` is a function that returns a value. A `val` is pretty similar with the difference that will always returns the same value. A `var` can return a value and also you can mutate it.

Comment: In your last example, you don't need the `var` to be private and have a manual setter if you want to get rid of the boilerplate. That's what I'd do if I needed such a thing: represent the mutable state somehow (`var` or something else) and expose it via the `def`. Then the "safety" and "quality" of this depends the actual real usage, I would tend to avoid it but in some cases it can make sense.

Comment: The reason why what you're trying to do is a lot of boiler plate for Scala's tastes is because using vars is not in Scala's taste in general. In over 10 years of Scala development, I have never had a reason to expose a public var on a class. I only ever use vars for things that are private/internal, to implement performance optimisations etc.